# Codeigniter Cronjob for godaddy hosting

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, cpanel

My website hosting server is Godaddy and website is www.5kcinema.com
I am using codeigniter framework
I have a script that runs and check whether movie is released today or not, if released date is today's date then movie is moved from upcoming movies to latest movies
My Controller file is Cron.php and function is index.

```
class Cron extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('listing_model');
    }

    public function index() {
        $tableName = 'movies_tbl m';
        $condition = "m.status=1 AND m.is_deleted=0 AND m.date_published='".date('Y-m-d')."'";
        $data = $this->listing_model->getAll($tableName, $condition, NULL, 1, 'object');

        if (count($data) > 0) {
            foreach ($data as $row) {
                $id = $row->id;
                $movie_data['mtype'] = 1;
                $this->listing_model->insert_update($tableName, $movie_data, $id); 
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I want this code to run in cron job every night at 12.01am

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a cron job on a CodeIgniter controller that all the URL does is run a query from an API, update the DB & send emails (from within CI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34118539/how-to-run-a-cron-job-on-a-codeigniter-controller-that-all-the-url-does-is-run-a)

Comment: not duplicate, that question is something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
1   0   *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php /path-to-your-public_html/www.5kcinema.com/index.php cron
```

Comment: /www.5kcinema.com/index.php cron, will this run the Cron.php index function ?

Comment: Yes `index` is the default method so it will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

you can choose cron time and then add this command

```
/usr/bin/curl --user-agent cPanel-Cron http://www.5kcinema.com/Cron/index/
```